# RubyCAS-Client question: Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubycas

I've installed RubyCAS-Client 2.1.0 as a gem and using Rails 2.3.10 on Windows 7. After creating a pristine Rails app, I started to follow the instructions on http://rubycas-client.rubyforge.org/, but as soon as I add

`CASClient::Frameworks::Rails::Filter.configure(
    :cas_base_url => "https://cas.example.foo/"
  )`

to environment.rb, I get the following exceptions when running script/console:

`C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:
611:in 'to_constant_name':ArgumentError: Anonymous modules have no name to be referenced by`

`C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:
469:in 'load_missing_constant':NameError: uninitialized constant ApplicationController`

I cannot start up server and I cannot generate controllers.  Is there a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you Included the following in environment.rb file:

require 'casclient'

require 'casclient/frameworks/rails/filter'